# didMoveToWindow: How will this method be called?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I spent time searching this without much success (including documentation), still left puzzled the `didMoveToWindow:` method.

Using `didMoveToWindow:` in a stock view project template:

```
-(void)didMoveToWindow{

    [super didMoveToWindow];

    // do something

}
```

gives the following warning:

> Warning: 'UIViewController' may not respond to 'didMoveToWindow'

It is not called on start up of view which is a surprise.
How will this method be called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`didMoveToWindow` is a method of `UIView`, not `UIViewController`.

Comment: brief is good rob but that's too brief. Can you elaborate on how it will it be called, short example?

Comment: Any time the value of `view.window` changes, the view sends itself the `didMoveToWindow` message.  This includes when `view.window` is first initialized (e.g. deep inside the nib loader, or when `[parentView addSubview:view]` is first done, if `parentView` is already in a window).

Answer (score 1):

In a UIViewController, you probably want viewDidAppear.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear: