# When to use didMoveToWindow method?

Tags: ios

I have been searching around for this particular method:`didMoveToWindow()` however I haven't found any concrete information.
Could someone explain why and when should someone use this method and when is it called?

Comment: hope this link help you=> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176341/didmovetowindow-how-will-this-method-be-called   =>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336706/ios-didmovetowindow-infinite-loop

Comment: I found these links before posting my question, but the answers are too brief and generic (at least for my taste!)

Answer (score 3):

This method is called by iOS when a UIView is added to the Window object.
You are supposed to override it to make your app do something at the same that.

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses can
>   override it to perform additional actions whenever the window changes.
>
> The window property may be nil by the time that this method is called,
>   indicating that the receiver does not currently reside in any window.
>   This occurs when the receiver has just been removed from its superview
>   or when the receiver has just been added to a superview that is not
>   attached to a window. Overrides of this method may choose to ignore
>   such cases if they are not of interest.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622527-didmovetowindow